# Is $\sec^{-1}(\sec(\pi/2)) = \pi/2$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

I think it shouldn't be defined as $\pi/2$ is not in the range of the function $\sec^{-1}(x)$

Wolfram confused me by giving the answer as $\pi/2$ : [Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eqmcttn631h)

But it mentions on another page that $\pi/2$ is not in the range of $\sec^{-1}(x)$:  [Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427esll6t2pt97)

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\pi/2$ is not in the domain of $\sec$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: @NotNotLogical No I meant $\pi/2$ is not in the range of sec inverse

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Is Wolfram giving a wrong answer?

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ccos%28%5Carccos%282%29%29

Comment: Thanks :) Wolfram is crazy I guess

Comment: It's very possible that Wolfram is using some kind of "generalized" trig function which would explain these weird results. I would be surprised if it made such a simple mistake...

Comment: $\arccos(2) = 1.316957897i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sec (\frac \pi 2)$ is not defined, so any expression that uses it is undefined. Alpha is pattern matching, using $\sec^{-1}(\sec(x))=x$, which is true for most $x$.  It is often sloppy on cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ross is correct. To expand, Wolfram is probably doing something like this:

It notices that you are calling $f^{-1}(f(x))$.

Assuming the inverse exists, AND that $f(x)$ is valid, the output is x.  Wolfram is simply pattern matching, probably to save computation. So Wolfram is never checking whether or not $f(x)$ is valid.

Similarly, to give a little more evidence this is what is happening, this happens here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Elog%280%29